# Convert UTF-8 encoded string to human readable string

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, ascii, decode

How to convert any UTF8 strings to readable strings.

Like : â¬ (in UTF8) is  €

I tried using Charset but not working.

Comment: What you are trying to achieve? Where the string comes from?

Comment: I just want to convert unreadable strings which are in UTF8 format to reable string (ASCII or other readable charset).

Comment: I got these type of strings from other questions'

Comment: That's not "UTF-8" but completely broken and unrepairable data. Strings do not have encodings.

Comment: Can you provide some unreadable UTF8 Strings?

Comment: What kind of output are you going for?  For the example input, are you looking for an output of `Uu?oaABC`?

Comment: can you tell me how to convert "â¬" to "€"?

Comment: i got this from this website : http://coderstoolbox.net/string/

Comment: You cannot convert "â¬" to "€". You can convert  "â[BPH](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/82/index.htm)¬" to "€" though... but you don't need to as long as you don't do encoding screwups like this in the first place.

Answer (score 1):

You are encoding a string to ISO-8859-15 with `byte[] b = "Üü?öäABC".getBytes("ISO-8859-15");` then you are decoding it with UTF-8 `System.out.println(new String(b, "UTF-8"));`. You have to decode it the same way with ISO-8859-15.

Comment: I am decoding with ISO-8859-15 also.

Comment: Well, yes, the line that works is doing it right `System.out.println(new String(b, "ISO-8859-15"));`. It decodes an ISO-8859-15 encoded string with ISO-8859-15 decoder. The other line decodes an ISO-8859-15 encoded string with UTF-8. Of course it won't work.

Comment: It is completely pointless to encode something as x and then decode it right after as x. It will not do anything, in the best case it will lose even more information.

Comment: I was just explaining the code in the question but the question was modified. Your comment and the down vote do not make any sense.

Comment: What he was doing in the old code was completely legit way to attempt to repair data. What you are suggesting in the answer is NO-OP that never makes sense. Just so I didn't misunderstand - you are suggesting to encode string as ISO-8859-15 and then decoding the resulting bytes as ISO-8859-15. It doesn't take much thinking to see that this will not do anything.

Comment: What is it that I am suggesting?!? I am just explaining why one of his lines prints what he expects but the other does not.

Comment: This: *You have to decode it the same way with ISO-8859-15.*. That's your suggestion, is it not?

Comment: He was encoding it with ISO-8859-15. If he wants to read it back he has the decode it with ISO-8859-15 and that is why the first statement prints it correctly. Again, I am explaining why his line prints what he expects.

Comment: @jdb yes, but my point is that if you are going to encode as ISO-8859-15 and then decode as ISO-8859-15, you might as well not do anything at all.

Comment: I am not the one who wrote that code. I was just explaining why it worked the way it did. My explanation is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to decode a byteArray encoded with "ISO-8859-15" with "UTF-8" format

```
        b = "Üü?öäABC".getBytes("ISO-8859-15");
        u = "Üü?öäABC".getBytes("UTF-8");

    System.out.println(new String(b, "ISO-8859-15")); // will be ok
    System.out.println(new String(b, "UTF-8")); // will look garbled
    System.out.println(new String(u,"UTF-8")); // will be ok
```

Comment: how to enable UTF-8 Console?

Comment: in Eclipse -> RunAs->Runconfiguration->commons->Encoding

Comment: It is completely pointless to encode something as x and then decode it right after as x. It will not do anything, in the best case it will lose even more information.

Comment: the question was updated @Esailija, this code was about the example previosly posted. I'll delete the post if it finishes like this

Answer (score 1):

This is not "UTF-8" but completely broken and *unrepairable* data. Strings do not have encodings. It makes no sense to say "UTF-8" string in this context. String is a string of abstract characters - it doesn't have any encodings except as an internal implementation detail that is not our concern and not related to your problem.

Comment: This is not true.  Strings **always** have an encoding.  Even in memory, the *logical* characters have to be *physically* encoded. Java strings use UTF-16 in memory.  If you have a String that contains UTF-16 encoded UTF-8 octets, then you could copy the character values as-is to a Byte array and then decode them back to a normal UTF-16 encoded string using the String constructor that takes a byte array and encoding as input.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I guess you read only the first sentence of my answer. The internal encoding is not ever relevant except when dealing with astral planes - in that case the choice of UTF-16 leaks to users. The data type to store binary data (encoded text for example) is  `byte[]`, not String.

Answer (score 1):

A string in java is already an unicode representation. When you call one of the *getBytes* methods on it you get an encoded representation (as bytes, thus binary values) in a specific encoding - ISO-8859-15 in your example. If you want to convert this byte array back to an unicode string you can do that with one of the string constructors accepting a byte array, like you did, but you must do so using the **exact same encoding** the byte array was originally generated with. Only then you can convert it back to an unicode string (which has no encoding, and doesn't need one).

Beware of the encoding-less methods, both the string constructor and the getBytes method, since they use the default encoding of the platform the code is running on, which might not be what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that you're assuming a java String is encoded with whatever you've specified in the constructor.  **It's not.**  It's in UTF-16.

So, `"Üü?öäABC".getBytes("ISO-8859-15")` is actually converting a UTF-16 string to ISO-8859-15, and then getting the byte representation of that.

If you want to get the human-readable format in your Eclipse console, just keep it as it is (in UTF-16) - and call `System.out.println("Üü?öäABC")`, because your Eclipse console will decode the string and display it as UTF-16.